# SQL get sum of a Column in Select

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I've got a table like the one shown below.

```
+------+-------+
|  id  | value |
+------+-------+
| 1    | 5     |
+------+-------+
| 2    | 9     |
+------+-------+
| 1    | 8     |
+------+-------+
| 3    | 10    |
+------+-------+
```

I'd like to be able to select three entries with the highest `value`. However, I want the ids to be grouped and the values to be added together. Here's the desired output:

```
+------+-------+
|  id  | value |
+------+-------+
| 1    | 13    |
+------+-------+
| 3    | 10    |
+------+-------+
| 2    | 9     |
+------+-------+
```

Currently, I've have this code:
`SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY id ORDER BY SUM(value) DESC LIMIT 3`
It is able to pick the top three rows (sorted by the `value` column) and group them by the ids. However, it returns with the highest `value` instead of adding them together, as seen below.

```
+------+-------+
|  id  | value |
+------+-------+
| 1    | 8     |
+------+-------+
| 3    | 10    |
+------+-------+
| 2    | 9     |
+------+-------+
```

What should I use to add together the `value` column on my `SELECT` statement?

Comment: At this point, 10 minutes in the company of any basic, introductory book or tutorial on mysql would prove beneficial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
select *
from (
  select id, sum(value) as total from t group by id
) x
order by total desc
limit 3
```

Or... in compressed syntax:

```
select id, sum(value) as total from t group by id order by total desc limit 3
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r5hCzxNWjJQyF7tNhQwW1t/0).